# React createPortal not passing current context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to pass context to an element manually rendered to the dom (because of a third-party library).

For some reason the context is not being passed correctly. I end up with:

> Portal Context: false

> Regular Context: true

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const AppContext = React.createContext(false);

function RenderAppContext() {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  return <>{JSON.stringify(context)}</>;
}

function App() {
  const portalRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      ReactDOM.createPortal(<RenderAppContext />, portalRef.current),
      document.createElement("div")
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={true}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <span>Portal Context:</span>&nbsp;
        <div ref={portalRef} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <span>Regular Context:</span>&nbsp;
        <RenderAppContext />
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-surf-wt0if4?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` is creating another react app, with completely separate contexts. Just `ReactDOM.createPortal(<RenderAppContext />, portalRef.current)` should be all that is needed for your portal. If you want to move where it is rendered to outside of the structure of your app just replace `portalRef.current` with the DOM element where you would like it to render (i.e. add an extra div to your body tag in your HTML give it an id of "portal" and then use `document.getElementById('portal')` or your preferred method of getting a reference to the element)

Comment: Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-darkness-5pbelt?file=/public/index.html